# iOS Metal buffer not honouring stride value

Tags: ios, metal

I have a per-instance uniform buffer where each element in the buffer is 64-bytes but I only use the first 16-bytes (float3) of each element in the vertex shader. I set the stride up to describe this. The problem is it does not stride over the other 48 bytes **unless** I add padding to the struct in the shader so that it is also 64 bytes.

```
// Particle Instance Position
vertexDescriptor.attributes[2].format = .Float3   // 16 bytes with padding.     
vertexDescriptor.attributes[2].offset = 0
vertexDescriptor.attributes[2].bufferIndex = 2
vertexDescriptor.layouts[2].stride = strideof(Particle)
vertexDescriptor.layouts[2].stepFunction = .PerInstance

...

commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(instanceUniformBuffer, offset:0, atIndex:2)
```

App side particle struct:

```
struct Particle {

    var position = float3()
    var prevPos = float3()
    var attractPoint = float3()

    var ref: DataRef!
    var state = State.Free

    enum State: Int {
        case Free = 0
        case Active
    }
}
```

And here's the corresponding Metal struct, i.e. `Particle.position` corresponds to `InstanceUniforms.instanceTranslate` in the shader. I expect the stride setup above to mean that this gets loaded with the `Particle.position` for each instance and the other 48 bytes of each `Particle` in the buffer is skipped over.

```
struct InstanceUniforms
{
    float3 instanceTranslate [[ attribute(2) ]];
};
```

Some sanity checks, everything makes sense:

```
sizeof(float3) 16
alignof(float3) 16
sizeof(Particle) 57
alignof(Particle) 16
strideof(Particle) 64
```

But it doesn't work unless I pad the shader struct out to 64 bytes:

```
struct InstanceUniforms
{
    float3 instanceTranslate [[ attribute(2) ]];
    float4 pad[3];
};
```

Otherwise for the second instance the shader actually sets `instanceTranslate` to the `Particle.prevPos` of the **first** element in the buffer, like it only strides over the size of the `InstanceUniforms` struct, regardless of what the stride is set to in the vertex descriptor.

I'm sure I must be doing something wrong here, it seems like you shouldn't need to pad your shader structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems like this is Just The Way It Is™ with Metal buffers: you have to pad the shader struct to match the stride of the app struct. I wouldn't think it would be that difficult for the Metal shader runtime to load *`stride`* bytes from the buffer and cast the first *`sizeof(MyShaderStruct)`* of them. Or autopad the struct when the pipeline state is attached. But these conveniences probably have efficiency implications.

Here's what my Swift / Shader structs look like now for reference:

**Metal:**

```
struct Particle
{
   float3 position;
   float3 prevPos;
   float4 color;
   float4 lineColor;
   float  scale;
   char   pad[60];
};
```

**Swift:**

```
struct Particle {
    var position = float3()
    var prevPos = float3()
    var color = float4()
    var lineColor = float4()
    var scale:Float = 0
    var gravity = float3()

    var data: DataRef!
    weak var physics: Physics? = nil
    var state = State.Free

    enum State: Int {
        case Free = 0
        case Active
    }
}

sizeof(Particle) 113
alignof(Particle) 16
strideof(Particle) 128
```